# .map() function inside ternary in react native jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Sorry this is newbie question, usually using `<List>{this.state.variable.map...}</List>` when in the component.But how to use .map function/any function inside conditional rendering in ternary operator?It was gave error syntax when using this syntax in below

Code:

```
{group.category !== "place" ? 
                <ListItem
                  title={"Foods"}
                  leftIcon={{
                    name: "food",
                    type: "material-community",
                    color: this.state.themeStore.primaryDarkColor
                  }}
                  subtitle={group.category}
                  subtitleStyle={{
                    color: this.state.themeStore.primaryDarkColor
                  }}
                  titleStyle={{ color: this.state.themeStore.primaryDarkColor }}
                  onPressRightIcon={() => {
                    this.showFoodsItem();
                  }}
                  rightIcon={{
                    name: "md-arrow-dropdown-circle",
                    type: "ionicon",
                    color: this.state.themeStore.primaryLightColor
                  }}
                />

                this.state.foods.map((item, i) => (
                  <ListItem
                    key={i}
                    title={item.name}
                    titleStyle={{
                      color: this.state.themeStore.primaryDarkColor
                    }}
                    avatar={{ uri: item.imageSource }}
                    rightIcon={{
                      name: "md-add-circle",
                      type: "ionicon",
                      color: this.state.themeStore.primaryLightColor
                    }}
                    onPressRightIcon={() => this.addExistingPlace(item)}
                  />
                )
 : (
                <View />
              )}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a problem with ternary operator. React expects that you'll return single child (or in a case of React 16+ - array of children) but you have multiple children.

You can workaround this problem by refactoring your code in a way that it will prepare array of `<ListItem>` as separate block of code (but outside of `return` statement of `render()` method) and then either put this array directly into returned JSX tree (in a case of React 16+) or by using additional wrapper like `React.createElement('div',{},...listItems)`

So your code may look like this:

```
render() {
    let items = [
        <ListItem
            title={"Foods"}
            leftIcon={{
                name: "food",
                type: "material-community",
                color: this.state.themeStore.primaryDarkColor
            }}
            subtitle={group.category}
            subtitleStyle={{
                color: this.state.themeStore.primaryDarkColor
            }}
            titleStyle={{color: this.state.themeStore.primaryDarkColor}}
            onPressRightIcon={() => {
                this.showFoodsItem();
            }}
            rightIcon={{
                name: "md-arrow-dropdown-circle",
                type: "ionicon",
                color: this.state.themeStore.primaryLightColor
            }}
        />
    ];
    this.state.foods.forEach((item, i) => (
        items.push(<ListItem
                key={i}
                title={item.name}
                titleStyle={{
                    color: this.state.themeStore.primaryDarkColor
                }}
                avatar={{uri: item.imageSource}}
                rightIcon={{
                    name: "md-add-circle",
                    type: "ionicon",
                    color: this.state.themeStore.primaryLightColor
                }}
                onPressRightIcon={() => this.addExistingPlace(item)}
            />
        )
    ));
    return group.category !== "place" ? React.createElement('div', {}, ...items) : <View/>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it is actually because it needs to return single child.